# Mathematics only with physics? What about biology and chemistry?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, applications, book-recommendation

In *[The Mathematical Mechanic](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8861.html)*, the author "reveal*s* how physics can simplify proofs and lead to quicker solutions and new theorems, and how physical solutions can illustrate why results are true in ways lengthy mathematical calculations never can".

I was wondering if some people have written books or papers (if it is possible at all) using the same kind of approach as Levi's with biology and chemistry instead of physics.

Comment: I seem to recall having read on either [*The Red Queen: Sex and the Evolution of Human Nature*](http://www.amazon.com/The-Red-Queen-Evolution-Nature/dp/0060556579) or on [*The Selfish Gene*](http://www.amazon.com/Selfish-Gene-Anniversary----Introduction/dp/0199291152/ref=sr_1_sc_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1413632041) about biological observations leading to mathematical breakthroughs.

Comment: When I see these arguments, I usually go "meh". It is impossible to derive the Pythagoras theorem with physical objects. It is only possible to show an approximation of it holds in some cases. Any actual proof will require to resort to abstract arguments which cannot be physically represented faithfully (e.g. how would you show that some three numbers form a Pythagorean triplet, if they are so large that they cannot be written down). You might want to say that the physical laws explaining some phenomena can be used to derive some theorem, but then you are back to abstract arguments.

Comment: Can you give an example of what exactly the author understands by solving math via physics? As physical theory is eventually captured mathematically, and since mathematics like geometric theories is arguably physical (you can imagine surfaces when you talk about $\{(x,y,z)\,|\,x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$), I can only come up with situations where one can argue away physical intuition in favor of straight math. What math problems can I solve via Newtons gravity, without actually talking about parabolas and vector fields? Would Turing modeling step by step tasks doable by humans a "biological" example?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: From your background, I assume you understand "deriving Pythagoras theorem" as derivations from axioms. Then again, it's a theorem called after guy who viewed is as an sight about the world - he's often pictured arguing with triangle tiles and he probably wasn't aware of any fixed axiom set he called his working ground. When and by whom was Pythagoras "derived", in your sense? To put a twist on your "It is impossible to derive the Pythagoras theorem with physical objects"..I think it's impossible to derive the theorem *without* physical objects: human, brain, paper, ink, etc. :)

Comment: Have a look at this question on *MathOverflow*: [*Examples of intuition from fields other than Physics to solve math problems*](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/181063/examples-of-intuition-from-fields-other-than-physics-to-solve-math-problems).

Comment: These are also related (and very interesting): [1](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/14782/what-are-some-applications-of-other-fields-to-mathematics), [2](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46883/examples-of-using-physical-intuition-to-solve-math-problems).

Comment: @Nico: I think the questioner asks for more than intuition. Otherwise, for example, if you identity and model causes for behavior of animals in the wild, the eventual real world distribution and fluctuations of population sure give "intuition" for how the solutions to the respective diff. equation you set up should look like. That's essentially the point I make above: If you got a definitive mathematical problem, and you want to *solve* it by arguing with physics/chemistry/biology, how do you want to obtain a quantitative solution without mathematically formulating the natural science you use.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I guess that you might want to look at the preface of the book (you can find it at the link provided) to understand what I mean.

Comment: @NikolajK You too.